# Hide the code apex in salesforce

Tags: apex, batch

how are you?
I would like to ask you how is it possible for me to hide my apex code in sales force I attach a screenshot of what I would like to achieve.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need to create a Managed Package, and then install that package in the org. You can use [First-Generation Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_build_release.htm) or [Second-Generation Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp.htm) with a namespace. Note that only `public` and `private` classes will be hidden; `global` code will be accessible in the subscriber org.